# how to pass query parameter and path paramter in .net http client getasyn method

Tags: c#, httpclient

I need to pass query parameters and path parameters to HttpClient GetAsync() method in .NET

File/{document_id}?version={version_number}

```cs
[Route("api/drs/v1/document/getdetails/{Id}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DocumentDetails(HttpRequestMessage details)
{
    // Debugger.Launch();
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            //String path=Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:8089/api/drs/v1/document/getdetail/"]);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.Write("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Failure");
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I can't pass both the parameter in GetAsync() method

Comment: Query parameters are part of the URL, this part is called the [Query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use next extension method for building your url. You can pass base url, path and dictionary of paramaters, which you need.

```
    public static Uri BuildUri(string baseUrl, string path, Dictionary<string, string> queryParams = null)
    {
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(baseUrl) {Path = path};

        if (queryParams != null)
        {
            var query = string.Join("&", queryParams.Select(x => $"{x.Key}={x.Value}").ToArray());
            uriBuilder.Query = query;
        }

        return uriBuilder.Uri;
    }
```